# what advantage postfix have over gmail server

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, postfix-mta

I configured a auto mail sender in ruby on rails ,set to send use gmail(the gmail account and password is there in the ruby code)

Then my boss ask me change use postfix...
Somehow lost in configure postfix to send mail.

what's the advantage of postfix over gmail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoiding "gmail" (external email provider) provides:

1. Better privacy protection
   Avoiding gmail removes unnecessary sending and receiving hop inside NSA.gov(.us) country in gmail case
2. Better trouble shouting
   Debugging delivery problems is simpler in email server under your admins control

**IMHO**: Using own email server is a good choice for most companies except mostly (very) small ones.  Running email server is pretty cheap for medium size companies.  "Gmail" (external email provider) may be a better choice when semi competent email postmaster skills are unavailable at acceptable price and privacy expectations are moderate or less.

It is not "one choice fits everyone" situation.

Comment: But gmail so much easier than setting up postfix. Must figure out postfix later